# why is insert on table locked?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

I am trying something with transaction levels on mysql.

I have Session S1 and Session S2. S1 is working with default isolation lavel Repeatable Read. For S2 i set Isolation Level Serializable.

Here is the szenario:

S1:

```
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5;
start transaction;
```

S2:

```
set session transaction isolation level serializable;
start transaction;
select count(*) from produkt;
```

S1:

```
select count(*) from produkt;
update kategorie set bezeichnung = 'Smartphone' where kategorieid = 1;
```

S2:

```
 insert into produkt(produktid, bezeichnung, kategorieid_fk) values (201, 'iPhone 8z', 1);
```

Can someone explain, why the `insert into produkt` from S2 is now blocked?

Here is the Tableschema:

```
    -- Exportiere Datenbank Struktur für transaktiondb
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `transaktiondb`;
    USE `transaktiondb`;


    -- Exportiere Struktur von Tabelle transaktiondb.kategorie
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kategorie` (
      `KategorieID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Bezeichnung` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`KategorieID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    -- Exportiere Struktur von Tabelle transaktiondb.produkt
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produkt` (
      `ProduktID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Bezeichnung` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `KategorieID_FK` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ProduktID`),
      KEY `fk_Produkt_Kategorie_idx` (`KategorieID_FK`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Produkt_Kategorie` FOREIGN KEY (`KategorieID_FK`) REFERENCES `kategorie` (`KategorieID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [deadlock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_deadlock) which MySQL describes as:

> A situation where different transactions are unable to proceed, because each holds a lock that the other needs. Because both transactions are waiting for a resource to become available, neither will ever release the locks it holds.

Looking closer at the [How to Minimize and Handle Deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html) reads:

> InnoDB uses automatic row-level locking. You can get deadlocks even in the case of transactions that just insert or delete a single row. That is because these operations are not really “atomic”; they automatically set locks on the (possibly several) index records of the row inserted or deleted.

Regarding the nature of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` the documentation describe that it only applies to scenarios where `inno_db_detect` is disabled, which is not the default configuration:

> The lock wait timeout value does not apply to deadlocks when innodb_deadlock_detect is enabled (the default) because InnoDB detects deadlocks immediately and rolls back one of the deadlocked transactions. When innodb_deadlock_detect is disabled, InnoDB relies on innodb_lock_wait_timeout for transaction rollback when a deadlock occurs. See Section 14.7.5.2, “Deadlock Detection and Rollback”.

Also, as a general tip, you'll often want to use `start transaction` followed as quickly as possible by a `commit` or `rollback` and not leave the session "hanging" to minimize these issues.